# Uninstall package with pip and uninstall the wheels built

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

If I `pip uninstall` a package, in this case llama-cpp-python, the whl file that it built upon installation is not removed.  I doesn't make sense to me why that would be left hanging around.  Why is this not done by default, and why is there no option to tell pip to remove wheels?  It would make sense to me that if you're uninstalling, you don't want an old wheel sitting on the filesystem.

I know that this can be worked around by adding the  --no-cache-dir when reinstalling, e.g.:

```
pip install  --no-cache-dir llama-cpp-python
```

Does pip have logic to reinstall wheels automatically when a different version of the package is being installed?

I had this problem because I wanted to change the build-related environment variables before installing the package.  I'm on linux if that's relevant.

Comment: When you uninstall a package using pip uninstall, it removes the box and its associated metadata but generally does not remove the wheel (.whl) files created during installation. This behavior is intentional and is designed to be a performance optimization. When reinstalling the same version, the wheel files are cached to avoid rebuilding the package from the source.

Comment: Note that you can also clean the cache using `python -m pip cache purge`